# SAP UI5 Paginated buttons are not working in my app using simple Table

Tags: javascript, pagination, frontend, sapui5

I am trying to replicate a simple pagination using Hbox buttons that are dynamically generated depending on the length of the JSON Model.

It looks like this,
[image: [table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0yxn.png)]

But the buttons are not working at all, Can you help me find the issue for this.
here are the code.
here is the controller js file.

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "comPagination1/model/models",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function(Controller, models, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("comPagination1.controller.Root", {

        onInit: function(oEvent) {
            var tableRow = 5;
            var dataObjects = 20;
            var pageNos = dataObjects / tableRow;
            var oHbox = this.getView().byId("paginationHbox");
            
            
            for (var i = 1; i <= pageNos; i++) {
                var buttonId = "button" + i;
                // make button.
                var b1 = new sap.m.Button({
                    text : i.toString(),
                    id: buttonId,
                    press : "pressPageNo"
                    }
                );
                // set ID and text of the button.  
                // b1.id = buttonId;
                // b1.setText(i);
                
                oHbox.addItem(b1);
            }
        },
        pressPageNo:function(){
                        var tableRow = 5;
                        var ID = this.getView().byId("button2").getText();   
                        alert("Page " + ID + " clicked");
                        //changing data, as per button clicked. 
                        //fetching the RAW Data from models.
                        var oProductsTemp = models.createProdutsModelRawJSON();
                        var pressedButton = 2; //lets take we pressed on page 2 button
                        var start = (tableRow*pressedButton)-tableRow;
                        var end = (tableRow*pressedButton);
                        //create final JSON data
                        var finalJSON = {
                            "ProductCollection":[]
                        };
                        for(var j = start; j < end; j++)
                        {
                            finalJSON.ProductCollection.push(oProductsTemp.ProductCollection[j]);
                        }
                        //make the new JSONModel, 
                        var finalJSONModel = new JSONModel(finalJSON);
                        this.byId("paginatedRTable").setModel(finalJSONModel);

            
        }
    });
});
```

here is the model file js.

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/Device"
], function(JSONModel, Device) {
    "use strict";

    return {

        createDeviceModel: function() {
            var oModel = new JSONModel(Device);
            oModel.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");
            return oModel;
        },
        //original JSON object, returning as raw JSON for page binding. 
        createProdutsModel: function(){
            var oProducts = {
                "ProductCollection": [
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "1",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "2",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "3",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "4",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "5",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "6",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "7",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "8",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "9",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "10",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "11",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "12",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "13",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "14",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "15",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "16",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "17",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "18",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "19",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "20",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        }
            ]};
        //showing only the 1st 5 data only. 
        //make the variable
        var data_5 = {
                "ProductCollection": []
        };
        //make the new array, showing just 5 objects. 
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            data_5.ProductCollection.push(oProducts.ProductCollection[i]);
        }
        var oProductsModel = new JSONModel(data_5);
        return oProductsModel;
    },
        createProdutsModelRawJSON: function(){
            var oProducts = {
                "ProductCollection": [
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "1",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "2",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "3",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "4",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "5",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "6",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "7",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "8",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "9",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "10",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "11",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "12",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "13",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "14",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "15",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "16",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "17",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "18",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "19",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "20",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG"
        }
            ]};
            return oProducts;
        }
    };
});
```

here is the XML View,

```html
<mvc:View controllerName="comPagination1.controller.Root" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page title="{i18n>title}">
                <content>
                    
<Table id="RTable" headerText="PaginationType" items="{ProductsModel>/ProductCollection}">
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text="ProductID" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Category" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="MainCategory" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="TaxTarifCode" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="SupplierName" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="WeightMeasure" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{ProductsModel>ProductId}" />
            </cells>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{ProductsModel>Category}" />
            </cells>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{ProductsModel>MainCategory}" />
            </cells>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{ProductsModel>TaxTarifCode}" />
            </cells>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{ProductsModel>SupplierName}" />
            </cells>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{ProductsModel>WeightMeasure}" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>

<Panel class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" width="100%">
<Hbox id="paginationHbox" 
    class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" 
    width="100%"
    alignItems="Center">
</Hbox>
</Panel>


<!--<Panel class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">-->
<!--        <Button text="1"></Button>-->
<!--        <Button text="1"></Button>-->
<!--        <Button text="1"></Button>-->
<!--        <Button text="1"></Button>-->
<!--        <Button text="1"></Button>-->
<!--        <Button text="1"></Button>-->
<!--        <Button text="1"></Button>-->
<!--        <Button text="1"></Button>-->
<!--        <Button text="1"></Button>-->
<!--        <Button text="1"></Button>-->
<!--</Panel>-->
                    
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

here are the files,
[FILES](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-q-hS2_H7s6wE53OVzm8wPcZaC_y6MJL/view?usp=share_link)

Here is the project export,
[project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14YeiDi_qaEYYQvlKE9viJ2yHG5VLFBJA/view?usp=share_link)

Thank you.

I tried a manual Pagination using simple logic, that just updates the model, from which the table is expecting the JSON Model data. With the press of the button, the model gets update and re-rendered on the table. However the button's logic seems to be not working for any reason.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please don't add code as links and add the relevant code in question itself

Comment: Pagination is built in, so you don't have to invent your own if you don't want to. I think the mistake is in `this.byId("paginatedRTable").setModel(finalJSONModel);`, where you set the model but you're not calling it `ProductsModel`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I found that M table has ListBase and I can enable growing items for it. But I am not sure if sap ui table has this feature.